# Excel 2016 - How to change the title of the Graph and make it more interactive with the selected data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

How to make the graph title change according to the selected data?
I have created a graph using the subtotal command:
=SUBTOTAL(9, D31:D558)
When I filter the data to select a specific information, the graph will change automatically according to the subtotal. It works great.
Unfortunately the title of the graph will not work with filtering.

So I used the following formula:
=IF(A5=214,"214 Dishwashers Map",(IF(A5=216,"216 Dishwashers Map","21 Dishwashers Map"))) 
and then set the graph title to cell A4, this will allow me to have the title change according to the information.

Unfortunately, the formula only works when I manually input the information in cell A5.

I was not able to have the formula look at the data after filtering and pick up the same information as in cell A5.

I tried to name (using name manager) the column and use that in the formula, but it did no work.

Any idea how to make the title more interactive without manual input?

Spreadsheet includes - several columns of data:
First Column has location information - Alphanumeric
Second Column has the first 3 digit numbers of the third column
Third Column has the full identification numbers
The rest of the columns have the actual data that are being added used in the Subtotal formula.

The second column is being filtered.

I am using the layout 5 from the Graph format.  I also use the line graph.

Any help you can give me, it is very much appreciated.  I have been trying to figure this out for the past 2 weeks.

Thank you in advance.

IS2017

Comment: Could you write how you are passing 214 and 216 to the Cell A5, any conditions behind this? And I'm sure that you have written the Formula in Cell A4 !!

Comment: Yes the formula is in Cell A4 - I just type manually the selection that I need to show as a title in the chart in Cell A5.

Comment: Whether the selection is 21, 214 or 216.   Thank you

Comment: I can suggest you two options. 1. Make a dropdown list with those 3 values in cell A5.  2. If these values are part of your database while filter, then use the Cell reference in A5 with filter.

Comment: Filtering is the ideal thing than I would like to do.  Unfortunately when I filter, the formula looks at visible and the not visible cells.  I just need for the formula to look at the visible cells.

Comment: I tried to use Define Name for the range but the formula will not recognize it.  It gives me the same results.

Comment: Perhaps the data you're typing in is numerical, but the data that your formula is retrieving is text, even though it looks like a number. Changing to `IF(A5="214"` might help.

Comment: I did try that but it did not work the way I needed it to work.  I am trying to have the formula assigned to a cell - for example A5 and select the information in the cell.  This works great if no filtering applied.  But once I filter the list, the A5 is not visible, so I need to have the formula to look at the next visible cell, ignores the invisible cell.  Thank you